# Remove elements before several patterns

Tags: r, regex

I have data about countries, e.g.

```
MWE <- list("Argentina -2.4 3.4", "Euro area 3.7 6.4")
```

I want to get a list with only the numbers. The is in my example, get `"-2.4 3.4" "3.7 6.4"` Note that my "country" can be in several words, so I cannot play as easily with spaces as I would want to.

I have managed to do that with only positive numbers, with

```
MWE_1 <- sub("^.*?(\\d)", "\\1",MWE)
```

But with negative numbers, or other words that are also possible before the numbers, my approach is not working.

I have tried using `|` but have failed , both

```
MWE_2 <- sub("^.*?(\\d)|^.*?(-)", "\\1",MWE)
MWE_3 <- sub("^.*?(\\d|-)", "\\1",MWE)
```

yield me the same result without the minus `"2.4 3.4" "3.7 6.4".

If my MWE is

```
MWE <- list("R text1 47 GDP -2.4 3.4", "Euro area but not UK CPI 3.7 6.4")
```

I want to get all text from "GDP" or "CPI", that is `GDP 2.4 3.4` and `CPI 3.7 6.4`.  It happens that

```
NMWE2 <- sub("^.*?(GDP|CPI)",NMWE)
```

does work, so I guess it is just a question on how to specify the minus sign, although escaping it with `\\-` does not work either.
`

Comment: `sub("^.*?([-+]?\\d)", "\\1",MWE)`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Two questions if you have time : why the `?` in `[-+]?\\d` ? Without it, it does not work any more on the second item. Why is my code not working (in particular, if I have a character pattern, your useful solution will not work any more)

Comment: Or `sub("^\\w+(?: \\w+)* ", "",MWE)`

Comment: What do you mean by "character pattern"?

Comment: f I want to remove all the elements before "Blabla1" Or "Blahblah2"

Comment: @AnthonyMartin What does that mean `the elements before "Blabla1" Or "Blahblah2"` You want to remove all before the numbers at the end?

Comment: If my MWE is  `MWE <- list("R text1 47 GDP -2.4 3.4", "Euro area but not UK CPI 3.7 6.4")`, and I want to get text from "GDP" or "CPI", that is `"GDP 2.4 3.4" "CPI 3.7 6.4"`.

Comment: So, what is that you want? Please edit the question with the exact requirements.

Comment: I might not be clear, your solution works perfectly but because I was trying to do a or condition on two alternatives that are very specific, negative or positive numbers. I had thought about my solution in a more general way as I was not aware of this possibility. But I do not understand why my code does not work, and therefore am not sure what to do if Y get the same problem in another more general context. My second MWE is not my real problem, just to try to understand the problem with my initial code

Comment: How do you differ between `Argentina -2.4 3.4` and `Euro area 3.7 6.4` and `R text1 47 GDP -2.4 3.4` and `Euro area but not UK CPI 3.7 6.4` The word before the number should not be in all caps?

Comment: My initial idea was to find a solution to the problem how to keep the values after a particular list, finite, of elements. In my initial question it was either after a digit or a minus sign, not being aware that I could do that in a simpler way. In my comment, it would be after either GDP or CPI, so something like `GDP|CPI`, but it happens that `NMWE2 <- sub("^.*?(GDP|CPI)",NMWE)` does work, so I guess it is just a question on how to specify the minus sign, although escaping it with `\\-` does not work either

Comment: Have you noticed my answer? Please check.

Comment: I will go through it tomorrow but thanks for the answer already

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives.  All use base R only.

**1) insert commas around 1st numeric field** Insert a comma before and after the first number replacing the spaces and then use `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = sub(" ([-0-9.]+) ", ",\\1,", unlist(MWE)), sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
         V1   V2  V3
1 Argentina -2.4 3.4
2 Euro area  3.7 6.4
```

**2) Repeated sub** Alternately replace the last space with comma twice.

```
mwe <- sub("(.*) ", "\\1,", sub("(.*) ", "\\1,", unlist(MWE)))
read.table(text = mwe, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
```

**3) strcapture**  `strcapture` takes a pattern and puts each capture group in a column:

```
strcapture("(.*) (.*) (.*)", unlist(MWE), 
  list(V1 = character(0), V2 = numeric(0), V3 = numeric(0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility :

```
gsub(".*? ([^ ]+ .[^ ]+)","\\1", MWE)
#> [1] "-2.4 3.4" "3.7 6.4"
```

We match a sequence of :

- anything (possibly containing spaces)
- a space
- some non space characters
- another space
- some more non space characters

And replace it by a group made of the latter 3.

---

edit : after reading your other question : [R remove elements based on several options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58716386/r-remove-elements-based-on-several-options/58717120#58717120) , it seems you want to extract all the info, in that case you might enjoy my `unglue` package.

```r
# install.packages("unglue")
library(unglue)
MWE <- list("Argentina -2.4 3.4", "Euro area 3.7 6.4")

unglue_data(MWE,"{Country} {numbers=[^ ]+ [^ ]+}")
#>     Country  numbers
#> 1 Argentina -2.4 3.4
#> 2 Euro area  3.7 6.4

unglue_data(MWE,"{Country} {number1=[^ ]+} {number2=[^ ]+}", convert = TRUE)
#>     Country number1 number2
#> 1 Argentina    -2.4     3.4
#> 2 Euro area     3.7     6.4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

More about it here: https://github.com/moodymudskipper/unglue/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a PCRE regex (mind to use `perl=TRUE` with `(g)sub`):

```
^(?:.*\b(GDP|CPI)\b|.*?([+-]?\d))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W1Xep0/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*\b(GDP|CPI)\b|.*?([+-]?\d))` - a non-capturing group matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `.*\b(GDP|CPI)\b` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last whole word `GDP` or `CPI` in the string (captured into Group 1, `\1`)
  - `|` - or
  - `.*?([+-]?\d)`  - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first optional `-` or `+`, and then 1 digit (captured into Group 2, `\2`).

[R demo](https://rextester.com/KTLP73994):

```
MWE <- c("R text1 47 GDP -2.4 3.4", "Euro area but not UK CPI 3.7 6.4", "Argentina -2.4 3.4", "Euro area 3.7 6.4")
gsub("^(?:.*\\b(GDP|CPI)\\b|.*?([+-]?\\d))", "\\1\\2", MWE, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "GDP -2.4 3.4" "CPI 3.7 6.4"  "-2.4 3.4"     "3.7 6.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the format always ending with two real numbers, maybe the following can do the work:

```
gsub(".*?\\s(\\-?\\d+.*)","\\1",MWE)
```

where the matching and extraction starts from real number (or from the sign of the first number)