# R remove elements based on several options

Tags: r, regex

I have data in a list, e.g.

```
MWE <- list("Argentina -2.0 1.4", "G20 6.9 0.7", "United Kingdom 1.3 2.3", "EU28 6.6 2.8")
```

Desired output :

```
[1] "Argentina"    "G20"           "United Kingdom" "EU28"
```

That is most of my identifier are only literal, but some have digits (G7, G20, EA15, ...) but a finite list.

I have tried to use OR conditions on  `gsub`but have failed so far. For instance,

```
> MWE_1 <- gsub("[^([:alpha:]|G20|EU28)]", "",MWE)
> MWE_1
[1] "Argentina20"    "G200"           "UnitedKingdom2" "EU2828"
```

It seems I have not found a way to use the or condition properly
Ideally, it would separate spaces based on whether it is between characters (e.g. United Kingdom) or not (e.g. -2,0 1,4) but I am fine with UnitedKingdom as a result

Comment: Your regex should be this `^([:alpha:]|G20|EU28)`  not `[^([:alpha:]|G20|EU28)]`

Comment: If you want to remove the numbers, try `MWE_1 <- gsub(" [+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?: \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*)*$", "",MWE)` See https://ideone.com/Y62kJQ

Comment: You did not use any OR conditions in your regex, it is a single negated character class matching any chars but the ones in the class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you elaborate a bit on your comment ?

Comment: `[^([:alpha:]|G20|EU28)]` is a negated character class that matches any 1 char but a `(`, letter, `|`, `G`, `2`, `0`, `|`, `E`, `U`, `8` and `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `gsub("\\s\\-?\\d+.*","",MWE)`, such that

```
> gsub("\\s\\-?\\d+.*","",MWE)
[1] "Argentina"      "G20"            "United Kingdom" "EU28"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the first capturing group and match the rest of the line.

In the replacement use the first capturing group.

```
^([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*|G20|EU28)\b.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ A-Za-z
  - `(?: [A-Za-z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and 1+ times a-zA-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `G20` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `EU28` Match literally
- `)\b` Close group followed by a word boundary
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RZrFd8/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/r0MyrF)

For example

```
MWE <- list("Argentina -2.0 1.4", "G20 6.9 0.7", "United Kingdom 1.3 2.3", "EU28 6.6 2.8")
MWE_1 <- gsub("^([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*|G20|EU28)\\b.*$", "\\1",MWE)
MWE_1
```

Output

```
[1] "Argentina"      "G20"            "United Kingdom" "EU28"
```

---

Using `:[[:alpha:]]` the line of code would look like

```
MWE_1 <- gsub("^([[:alpha:]]+(?: [[:alpha:]]+)*|G20|EU28)\\b.*$", "\\1",MWE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern removes whitespace followed by a positive or negative numbers that might have a decimal:

```
gsub("\\s+\\-?\\d+\\.?\\d*", "", MWE)
[1] "Argentina"      "G20"            "United Kingdom" "EU28"
```

This returns the everything in the string up to whitespace followed by a number (positive or negative):

```
gsub("(.*?)\\s+\\-*\\d+.*", "\\1", MWE)
[1] "Argentina"      "G20"            "United Kingdom" "EU28"
```

Answer (score 1):

My variant:

```
MWE <- list("Argentina -2.0 1.4", "G20 6.9 0.7", "United Kingdom 1.3 2.3", "EU28 6.6 2.8")

gsub("\\s+", "", gsub("[0-9\\-]+\\.+[0-9]+", "", MWE))
# [1] "Argentina"     "G20"           "UnitedKingdom" "EU28"
```

Here, the inner `gsub()` looks for patterns that:

- contain one or more `-` or digits
- followed by one or more `.`
- followed by one or more digits

And removes the matched patterns (i.e., replaces them with `""`).

The outer `gsub()` then strips all whitespaces from this result.

Advantages: you're calling `gsub()`.

Disadvantages: you're calling `gsub()` twice.